# How to inherit Android style attribute?

Tags: java, android, styles

I've recently tried adopting a style-based approached to my android app. However, I'm stuck with this dilemma.

In my layout file I originally had this:

```
 <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_event_buttons"
         style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <ImageButton
             android:id="@+id/btn_create_event"
             style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:contentDescription="@string/btn_save"
             android:src="@drawable/content_save"
             android:text="@string/btn_save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my styles.xml I tried doing this with no luck:

```
<style name="Buttons" parent="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

I already tried different variations of the above like:

`?android:buttonBarButtonStyle`

`?attr:buttonBarButtonStyle`

`@android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle`

`@android:buttonBarButtonStyle`

I also tried:

```
<item name="style">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
```

to no avail.

My app won't compile because it can't find the buttonBarButtonStyle resource.

This is how I applied it. My other styles work fine if I just inherit the common themes like Holo, etc.

```
<ImageButton
     style="@style/Buttons"
     android:id="@+id/btn_create_event"
     android:contentDescription="@string/btn_save"
     android:src="@drawable/content_save"
     android:text="@string/btn_save" />
```

Comment: By the way, I have this in my manifest 
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
So I don't think I'm running it out of an unsupported api level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer to be similar to this post:
[How does an android:attr style work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869184/how-does-an-androidattr-style-work)

Turns out this style is private and you may need to copy it completely to be able to pull it off. :(

Comment: You cannot have more than one same named custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that applying `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to the button attributes removes the borders, which makes the button act like the android buttonbar (after extending the `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle` as you have.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned) explains it well

Answer (score 0):

For AppCompat, you can inherit from the Parent style.  For example, add this to each button.

```
<style name="MyBorderlessButtonBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">

    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>

    <!--more items-->

</style>
```