# New to android need to understand "?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Tags: java, android

I was going through [Lars Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) on using Fragments and I came across the following code:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

I am not sure what `?android:attr` means, especially the question mark.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
android:attr
```

is an attribute.

In specific,

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

means: "the size (height) of the action bar".
**?** is a special character that means it's an Android internal feature.

Comment: answer includes some mystery. More detail needed.

Comment: @oiyio **?android** indicates a *system* feature. Not a customized/customizable one. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of write Numerical number in value of `android:layout_marginTop` , you can use the height specified by  [actionBarSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarSize)  like  [an Example in  Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html#TopMargin) .

You can use  `?android:attr` or `?attr` [ in case support library ] If you need to use any android attributes[ `attr` ] can be found in [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html)

**For** More Description about `?android:attr` [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008150/how-does-androidattr-activatedbackgroundindicator-work) ,[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869184/how-does-an-androidattr-style-work/10869421#10869421)

Comment: Is there a built in 2 x ?attr/actionBarSize?

Comment: @santafebound Do you mean multiple action bar size value??

Comment: @ahmedhamdy Yes

Comment: I think there isn't built in for multiple action bar size value or setting it as `2x actionBarSize`.
I think you need to setting numerical value into `values.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

While building android apps, one requires  to know the properties of the Android client. Such as screen size etc. One such method is by using `android:attr` which is android attributes. Here you have mentioned to return a specific attribute by mentioning the keyword after / symbol. Here the keyword is `actionBarSize`.

The `?` symbol is an operator which is used to access system configurations and properties in Android

Comment: Where can you get a list of all of those configurations and properties, using the same method?