# ?android:attr/actionBarSize not working in only one device. Why?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, scrollview, android-scrollview

**Android experience level: Novice.**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="false">
```

I have applied top margin to the `ScrollView` which is the height of `actionBar`. That works well in two of my physical devices properly but not in one. Why the one device does not utilize the value?

Screenshots attached.

**Lenovo A7000 with Marshmallow 6.0 Stock ROM:**

Below the action bar, one or two lines are not visible. Probably behind the `actionBar`.

[image: Lenovo A7000 with Marshmallow 6.0 Stock ROM]

**HTC phone and Samsung tablet: The text appears fine.**

[image: HTC Desire 620G with KitKat Stock ROM]
[image: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2]

Comment: did you checked from what folder res are getting picked?

Comment: do you use AppCompat? Try changing margin to `?actionBarSize`

Comment: Yes. AppCompat is used.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20773334/3678308

Comment: That's what I've used @ExceptionLover. `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing attribute value to **?attr/actionBarSize** rather than using **?android:attr/actionBarSize**