# Using style attributes in style sheets

Tags: android

I have created a simple button and applied the following style to it

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
```

but on checking R.style i did not find any style by this name.
rather found this in R.styleable

Can we also use this value to any item in style sheet if yes then kindly update to which attribute.

thanks

Comment: `?android:` means it's android **internal**. Not your accessible files.

Comment: Read this, u may get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869184/how-does-an-androidattr-style-work

Comment: @Panther yes it helped. another point that is not clear is the difference between R.styleable and R.attr . i have seen a very entries in so but not very clear. if you have any idea kindly do update

Comment: R.styleable is the custom attributes that one set for Views. Like i can extend the `ImageView` to add custom functionalities to it and add `custom attributes to it via xml` and use that in my code. Read about custom attributes here `http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr`

Comment: i meant android.R.styleable and android.R.attr. does this mean the R.styleable contains all that is in R.attr